# Presenting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am presenting a table view controller after taking a picture with this code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo");

    [self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];


    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

        self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

            NSLog(@"A photo was taken!");



            CCCameraViewController *viewController = [[CCCameraViewController alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
            [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

            [self.navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
            [self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

            self.navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

            viewController.tableView.tintColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:49.0 / .0 green:.0 / .0 blue:.0 / .0 alpha:1.0];



            [self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But when I run and after I take the picture and try to present `CCcameraviewController`, i get this termination error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a
>   nil modal view controller on target .'

Comment: First dismis the  'imagePickerController' the you can push or present.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
[self.tabBarController presentViewController:self.navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's `self.navController` not `self.viewController`

Comment: I changed it but when i run and present it I get this error terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UITabBarController: 0x15f625b00>.'

Answer (score 0):

you should set `self.viewController` first. Like this :

```
CCCameraViewController *viewController = [[CCCameraViewController alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
self.viewController = viewController;
```